# Ruby on rails server not refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Something really strange is happening after I updated to Rails 3.2.4.

I create a new app, and use scaffold to generate a model called FOO. With the local serve I can create a new FOO, but then the in FOOs' index.html the new FOO does not appear. It does only after I restart the local server.

The same behavior is seen when I push heroku.

It's really weird, also because if I put /FOOs/1 in the URL I can see the show page of the newly created FOO (before restarting the server I mean). So the record is there, but it is not listed in the index.html. The latter is just doing a trivial

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

What is happening here?

Rails version is 3.2.4

Comment: You should upgrade Rails to 3.2.5. 3.2.4 had some regressions, and 3.2.5 came out less than a day later to correct them. If your app worked on 3.2.3 and mysteriously stopped working after the upgrade, 3.2.5 will probably fix it.

Comment: What does your controller index action look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 3.2.5 solved the problem!